# when I try to print more than one argument, it won't print

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape a wep-page, using cheeiro, and  I get the value from the selector,

when I use only one argument, for example 'a.text--title' it prints fine, 
but when I use both `'a.text--title' , 'div.artist-name'` it's not printing anything..

what am I doing wrong ?

```
 $('a.text--title' , 'div.artist-name').each(function(i, element) {
 var mailoutput ;
                mailoutput = $(this).text();
              console.log(mailoutput);
        });
```

Comment: The jquery function takes only one argument.

Comment: oh thank u, do u know how to save them in two different objects , I can manipulate the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two selectors go in one string, not as two arguments.

```
$('a.text--title, div.artist-name')
```

To log alternating names and titles:

```
var names = $(‘div.artist-name')
var titles = $('a.text--title')
for ( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ) {
    var name = names.eq(i).text()
    var title = titles.eq(i).text()
    console.log( 'name:’, name, 'title:', title )
}
```

Comment: do u know how to save two selectors into different variable ?

Comment: `var title = $('a.text-title');` `var name = $('.artist-name')` ?

Comment: and should i delete the string inside the $()

Comment: Sorry but I’ve lost you. What are you trying to do?

Comment: all I'm trying to do is, print it like this way :
'name : title
name : title 
name: title '

but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: u don't save it in text, like $(this).text()
cause when I do ur way it print all selectors with it

Comment: Actually my answer was incomplete, glad you got the rest of the way by yourself! Happy to help.

Comment: which part was not complete ? so that I know

Comment: I forgot to define `name` and `title` at first, then edited the answer.